# What are a digital dementia and a pseudo debility?

Tags: definition

I'm a fan of Psychology.

I'd like to know what "pseudo debility" is. Unfortunately, I don't know what it means in English. This is my free translation from Russian.

I've encountered the terms "pseudo debility" and "digital dementia" on resources that popularize science. But I still haven't found a generally accepted definition.

This "pseudo debility" is the simplification and flattening of delirium in the modern world. In the past, delirium was more saturated, unique and striking imagination.

I'd like to know:

- What is it?
- Who invented and studied it?

### Links

- [Цифровое слабоумие: кто на самом деле глупеет от гаджетов?](https://newtonew.com/school/digital-amentia)
- [Псевдодебильность и слабоумие общества. Андрей Курпатов на QWERTY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGB_z3mt_wI)
- The video above refers to such authors as [Manfred Spitzer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_Spitzer) and [Theo Compernolle](https://sites.google.com/site/compernolleconsulting3/)
- [Digitale Demenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_Spitzer#Digitale_Demenz) is a book by [Manfred Spitzer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_Spitzer)

Comment: Could you include all sources (and what you learned from them, and what is unclear) in a cohesive edit to your question (I.e., not just a 'materials' section; introduce each where relevant) ?

Comment: The third sub question seems unrelated. Try to ask a focuses question, one per post. If need be, ask multiple questions.

Comment: @StevenJeuris, thanks for your support. I'll try to be consistent.

Comment: @AliceD, you are right. I've fixed this.

Comment: You just renamed 'materials' to 'Links'. This does not address my previous comment, i.e., "introduce each where relevant". In the sources where you encountered 'pseudo debility' and 'digital dementia', how was the term introduced there? Is the paragraph which includes 'the simplification and flattening' your definition, or a quote? Where does this come from? Also please incorporate the exact Russian term, i.e., "This is my free translation from Russian: <russian>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Digital dementia" seems to be (from de.wiki link) an idiosyncratic (and pejorative) term used to describe a high dependence on portable electronics like smartphones, notebooks. See e.g.

- ["Why Smartphone Dependence Is Ravaging a Generation"](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/why-smartphone-dependence-is-ravaging-a-generation_us_599b7493e4b0ac90f2cba962) obviously from an alarmist proponent of this phenomenon, or ["Mobile phone overuse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_overuse) on Wikipedia for a more neutral perspective.
- the more general term seems to be ["overuse of technology"](http://ssrc.ie/blog/2018/01/23/the-impact-the-overuse-of-technology-has-on-humans-and-the-environment/). Calling it "dementia" probably relates to an influential article (discussed in the previous link) titled ["Is Google Making us Stupid?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_Google_Making_Us_Stupid%3F). Another pejorative term is ["digital zombie"](https://www.wsj.com/articles/no-your-children-arent-becoming-digital-zombies-1444400129).

From the absence of sources you provided, I don't know what "pseudo debility" might be, but based on your def "simplification and flattening of delirium in the modern world" it doesn't sound terribly related to "digital dementia" in the sense used by Manfred Spitzer.

Comment: It seems that these are indeed idiosyncratic terms to enhance the attraction of public attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Digital pseudo debility is used by a popular Russian psychiatrist Andrey Kyrpatov to describe a dependence, addiction to information on smart phones, ipads, etc.  people think they are getting smarter when in reality they exhibit all signs of dependence .  He also describes in medical terms what exactly happens in a brain of an addicted person. So digital dementia is the closest to digital pseudo dibility. 
https://snob.ru/selected/entry/99993 Translated excerpt from the article :
“ Only one thing differs from clinical debility and pseudo-debility: there is no way to make/force, under any circumstances,  a clinical moron to think; the state of his grey matter won’t allow that. 
But the "gray matter" of information psevdodebil is safe, and, in principle, his brain can be trained. But why? No, why not to train him, and why should he train it? What's the point? What is the motivation?  Will he somehow be respected for this in a special way? Or, on the contrary, will they shame that he is a fool? Or he will not survive without it? Not.”

What is pseudo debility? By Andrey Kurpatov https://www.erarta.com/ru/museum/news/report/detail/news-02928/

Kill the idiot inside you. Information pseudo-debility and digital dementia.https://cont.ws/@adviser095/913341